# What is the proper way to override threading.excepthook in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance, exception, overloading

I am trying to handle uncaught exceptions that occur when I run a thread. The python documentation at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.excepthook) states that "`threading.excepthook()` can be overridden to control how uncaught exceptions raised by `Thread.run()` are handled." However, I can't seem to do it properly. It doesn't appear that my `excepthook` function is ever excecuted. What is the correct way to do this?

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def excepthook(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("In excepthook")

def error_soon(timeout):
  time.sleep(timeout)
  raise Exception("Time is up!")

my_thread = MyThread(target=error_soon, args=(3,))
my_thread.start()
time.sleep(7)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`threading.excepthook` is a function that belongs to the `threading` module, not a method of the `threading.Thread` class, so you should override `threading.excepthook` instead with your own function:

```
import threading
import time

def excepthook(args):
    print("In excepthook")

threading.excepthook = excepthook

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def error_soon(timeout):
    time.sleep(timeout)
    raise Exception("Time is up!")

my_thread = MyThread(target=error_soon, args=(3,))
my_thread.start()
time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: Python 3.8+ is required for overriding excepthook: [excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.excepthook)